How to use a list field "keyword" or "text" with semantic search in Opensearch
I have an opensearch schema in which one of the field is called products. products contains a list of products the document is relevant about.
I have a user query parser which identifies which products the user is talking about. I want to do semantic search or hybrid search on this schema, but with a filter on the products field.
user input products: ['prod-1', 'prod-2']
value of products in a document: ['prod-1', 'prod-3'] - This document must be searched because product 1 is there.
Schema:
{
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "number_of_shards": 1,
        "number_of_replicas": 1,
        "knn": true,
        "knn.space_type": "cosinesimil"  
      }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
"page_content": {
            "type": "text"
        },
        "products": {
            "type": "keyword"
        }
}}


Is this the right and ideal way to create schema as products are a list?
def format_query(text, query_vector, text_fields, vector_field, alpha, method, limit, filter_products=[]):
    # Define the query
    if method == 'semantic':
        # Semantic search using only the vector similarity
        base_query = {
                "knn": {
            vector_field: {
                    "vector": query_vector,  # Replace with your actual query vector components
                        "k": limit  # Adjust the number of nearest neighbors you want to retrieve
                        }
                      }
                    }
    elif method == 'hybrid':
        # Hybrid search combining text search scores and vector similarity
        base_query = {
            "function_score": {
                "query": {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": text,
                        "fields": text_fields
                    }
                },
                "functions": [
                    {
                        "script_score": {
                            "script": {
                                "source": f"cosineSimilarity(params.query_vector, doc['{vector_field}']) * params.alpha + (1.0 - params.alpha)",
                                "params": {"query_vector": query_vector, "alpha": alpha}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "boost_mode": "replace"
            }
        }
    else:
        raise ValueError("Unsupported search method")
    # Define the filter for products if products is provided and not empty
    
    filter_query = []
    if filter_products:
        filter_query.append({
            "terms": {
                "products": filter_products
            }
        })
    
    # Combine the base query and filter query
    if filter_query:
        query = {
            "bool": {
                "must": [base_query],
                "filter": filter_query
            }
        }
        #query = base_query
    else:
        query = base_query
    
    print(query)
    return query

This query returns nothing if filter_products are not empty
I have tried various methods, validated the uploaded data and schema. It would be great if someone could please help me solve this.

How KQL tag is relevant here? If it is not relevant, click edit and remove it.
